# How to set linewidth with a variable with Tradingviews pine script

Tags: pine-script

I try to plot a line where i want to set linewidth with a variable.

```
waveLinewidth = waveNum > 50 and src > src[1] ? 2 : 
   waveNum > 50 and src <= src[1] ? 1 : 
   waveNum < 50 and src < src[1] ? 2 : 
   waveNum < 50 and src >= src[1] ? 1 : 1

plot(waveNum + -50, color=waveColor, linewidth=waveLinewidth, transp=0, title="Buy Wave")
```

I do exactly the same if-else statement with waveColor variable but with diff. color. And that works. But when I add linewidth=waveLinewidth to plot() I get this error message:

```
line 147: Cannot call `plot` with arguments (series[float], color=series[color], linewidth=series[integer], transp=literal integer, title=literal string); available overloads: plot(series[float], const string, series[color], input integer, input integer, input bool, input integer, input float, series[integer], input bool, series[float], const bool, input integer, string) => plot; plot(fun_arg__<arg_series_type>, const string, fun_arg__<arg_color_type>, input integer, input integer, input bool, input integer, input float, series[integer], input bool, series[float], const bool, input integer, string) => plot;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
available overloads: plot(series[float], const string, series[color], input integer, input integer, input bool, input integer, input float, series[integer], input bool, series[float], const bool, input integer, string)
```

`linewidth`'s type is `integer`, which means its value must be known before script execution. So, you cannot assign a variable to that.

It works with `color` because, the type of `color` is `series[color]`, its value can be determined at runtime.